# Postfix Mail User's restriction - specified mail user alone on centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I have a mail server in linux and the MTA is POSTFIX. I need to configure the restricted settings in mail users level alone.

For Exmaple.

My mail server hostname is: *example.com* and my mail user's are listed below.

1. abc@example.com
2. xyz@example.com
3. 123@example.com

**Requirement:**

1. The mail user's *abc@example.com* and *xyz@example.com* can't receive any mail from the internal domain (i.e) internal users [*123@exmaple.com*] but both the mail user's can able to send mail to other domains like gmail,yahoo and hot mail.
2. The mail user's *abc@example.com* and *xyz@example.com* can able to send the mail to internal user "*123@exmaple.com*"
3. There is no restrict for the mail user "*123@example.com*".